# How tomcat call the @requestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC, while going through the various tutorial online got this doubt, I encountered several syntax of writing the function under @requestMapping annotation
For eg.

Syntax 1:
'''

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }
```

'''
Syntax 2:
'''

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printer()
    {
        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("hello");
        m.addObject("Welcome", "Success !! Krishna");
        return m;
    }
```

'''
Syntax 3:
'''

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printer(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //Some code
    }
```

'''

My question is :

How Tomcat knows which parameters my function is expecting and how does it provide the requested parameter to my function

Comment: Tomcat doesn't know anything about it. It only invokes the Spring DispatcherServlet, which is typically mapped to "/" (i.e. all the paths). It's Spring which then examines the path, finds the controller method mapped to that path,  and calls it with the expected arguments. Here's the Spring MVC documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat only provides the actual instance of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` (i.e. Those object defined in the `Servlet` API) .The actual work that decide and resolve the argument values is done by [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc). It then calls the controller method with the resolved values.

It basically boils down to using Reflection API to get the type information of the parameter of the matched controller method (e.g its annotation setting , data type etc). Based on these type information, it resolves the values based on the rules define in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods) . After all values are resolved , it uses Reflection API again to invoke this controller method with the resolved value.

Pseudo codes looks likes:

```java
FooController controller = context.getBean(FooController.class);
Method matchedControllerMethod = findMatchedControllerMethod(controller, httpServletRequest);

int parameterCount = matchedControllerMethod.getParameterCount().
Object[] resolvedParamValues = new Object[parameterCount];

for (int i = 0; i < parameterCount; i++) {
   Parameter param = matchedControllerMethod.getParameters(i);

   if(param.getType().equals(ModelMap.class)){
        resolvedParamValues[i] = Util.getModelMap();
   }else if(param.getType().equals(HttpServletRequest.class)){
        resolvedParamValues[i] = httpServletRequest;
   }else if(param.getType().equals(HttpServletResponse.class)){
        resolvedParamValues[i] = httpServletResponse
   }else if{
      .......
      ........
   }

}
matchedControllerMethod.invoke(controller ,resolvedParamValues);
```

In reality , the codes are much more fancy than that. For example, it uses strategy pattern to replace those if-else check with an abstraction called [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java). In other words , by looking at all the [implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` ,you can know how it resolves the arguments for all possible cases.

Answer (score -1):

It has less to do with requestMapping and more to do with requestParam which would be responsible for deciphering the type of parameters.
Read more:
https://dzone.com/articles/using-the-spring-requestmapping-annotation